# Проблема с запуском gulp

Tags: gulp, npm, rxjs

При запуске gulp выдет вот такую ошибку

```
[18:54:24] Using gulpfile D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\gulpfile.js
[18:54:24] Starting 'vendorCss:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'vendorCss:build' after 22 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'vendorJs:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'vendorJs:build' after 6.87 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'html:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'html:build' after 2.09 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'js:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'js:build' after 7.4 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'scss:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'scss:build' after 4.36 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'css:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'css:build' after 942 μs
[18:54:24] Starting 'fonts:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'fonts:build' after 780 μs
[18:54:24] Starting 'image:build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'image:build' after 2.54 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'build'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'build' after 33 μs
[18:54:24] Starting 'webserver'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'webserver' after 34 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'watch'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'watch' after 15 ms
[18:54:24] Starting 'default'...
[18:54:24] Finished 'default' after 3.85 μs
[18:54:28] Starting 'js:build'...
[18:54:28] Finished 'js:build' after 2.63 ms
[Mefisto] Reloading Browsers...
D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:77
    throw e;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.browser:reload (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\internal-events.js:23:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at AnonymousObserver._onNext (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\internal-events.js:95:27)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.next (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1828:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1762:31)
    at AnonymousObserver.tryCatcher (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:63:31)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:5883:51)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1762:31)
    at InnerObserver.next (D:\HTML and CSS\Training\site\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:5409:14)
```

Вот gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),
  prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  rimraf = require('rimraf'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
  reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
  vendor: {
    js: 'app/js/',
    css: 'app/css/'
  },

  dist: { //Тут мы укажем куда складывать готовые после сборки файлы
    html: 'dist/',
    js: 'dist/js/',
    scss: 'dist/css/',
    css: 'dist/css/',
    img: 'dist/img/',
    fonts: 'dist/fonts/'
  },

  app: { //Пути откуда брать исходники
    html: 'app/*.html', //Синтаксис src/*.html говорит gulp что мы хотим взять все файлы с расширением .html
    js: 'app/js/*.js', //В стилях и скриптах нам понадобятся только main файлы
    scss: 'app/css/*.scss',
    css: 'app/css/*.css',
    img: 'app/img/**/*.*', //Синтаксис img/**/*.* означает - взять все файлы всех расширений из папки и из вложенных каталогов
    fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
  },

  watch: { //Тут мы укажем, за изменением каких файлов мы хотим наблюдать
    html: 'app/**/*.html',
    js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
    scss: 'app/css/**/*.scss',
    css: 'app/css/**/*.css',
    img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
  },

  clean: './dist'
};


var config = {
  server: {
    baseDir: "./dist"
  },
  host: 'localhost',
  tunnel: true,
  port: 9000,
  logPrefix: "Mefisto"
};

gulp.task('vendorJs:build', function() {
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js')) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.vendor.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в app
});

gulp.task('vendorCss:build', function() {
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.css')) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.vendor.css)) //И в app
});

gulp.task('html:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html)) //Выплюнем их в папку build
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    })); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений
});

gulp.task('js:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.js) //Найдем наш main файл
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //Инициализируем sourcemap
    .pipe(uglify()) //Сожмем наш js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) //Пропишем карты
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в build
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    })); //И перезагрузим сервер
});

gulp.task('scss:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.scss) //Выберем наш main.scss
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //То же самое что и с js
    .pipe(sass()) //Скомпилируем
    .pipe(prefixer()) //Добавим вендорные префиксы
    .pipe(cleanCSS()) //Сожмем
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.scss)) //И в build
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('css:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.css) //Выберем наш main.css
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //То же самое что и с js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css)) //И в build
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.img) //Выберем наши картинки
    .pipe(imagemin({ //Сожмем их
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{
        removeViewBox: false
      }],
      use: [pngquant()],
      interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img)) //И бросим в build
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
  gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', [
  'vendorCss:build',
  'vendorJs:build',
  'html:build',
  'js:build',
  'scss:build',
  'css:build',
  'fonts:build',
  'image:build'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('html:build');
  });

  watch([path.watch.scss], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('scss:build');
  });

  watch([path.watch.css], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('css:build');
  });

  watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('js:build');
  });

  watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('image:build');
  });

  watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('fonts:build');
  });
});

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Закомментируйте строку `tunnel:true` должно помочь.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Почему мешает строка `tunnel:true`?

Comment: Собственный опыт, такая же проблема была когда-то. Еще проблема решается переустановкой browser-sync.

Answer (score -1):

выберите порт  8081
Закомментируйте строку tunnel:true